# preventing against loss of internet in python

Tags: python-2.7, serial-port

I understand that I can make sure a script that uses the internet takes no action unless it is connected to the net by using code like this.

```
import time
import json
import urllib

try:
    response = urllib.urlopen('http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23monty')
except IOError:
    time.sleep(15)
    continue
j =json.loads(response.read())
```

What I have found however, is that when I shut off my router after this point in the script, the script can freeze up. Turning the internet back on will not un-stick the stuck script.
What is a non-stick method? I need a script to be able to survive temporary loss of internet and serial port connections.

Answer (score 0):

This has probably something to do with the timeout of your request (defaults to socket's timeout if I remember well). try this:

```
import time
import json
import urllib

try:
    response = urllib.urlopen('http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23monty', timeout=10)
except IOError:
    time.sleep(5)
    continue
j =json.loads(response.read())
```

Best regards,

Sullivan

Comment: I tried your code and it didn't help. Sorry Sullivan. It brought up an error.